# Delete Query returning Value even when there is no record in database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
            include "conn.php";
            include "session.php";
            $name_enterd=$_GET['Name'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM myDB.Mynew WHERE firstname='$name_enterd' OR lastname='$name_enterd'";
            echo "<br>";
            $result=$conn->query($sql);
            if($result==1)
            {
                echo "<br> Data deleted successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "No Data Found<br>";
            }
        ?>
```

when I run this code 1st time it works properly by deleting the data. But when i run it again it still gives me the same answer" Data Deleted Successfully" even there is no data with that value exists.
i.e $result still gets value1.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look more like this:

```
<?php
        include "conn.php";
        include "session.php";
        $name_enterd=$_GET['Name'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM myDB.Mynew WHERE firstname='$name_enterd' OR lastname='$name_enterd'";
        echo "<br>";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if($result->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            echo "<br> Data deleted successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No Data Found<br>";
        }
    ?>
```

Specifying `rowCount` gives you just the number of rows affected by the query

Answer (score 0):

Even when the query only affects 0 rows it has still completed successfully, so you would expect $result to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the correct output. When doing that query, you're asking the database to check if there is data with that firstname or lastname and delete it. Even if there is no data with that matches it, the query has still run successfully.

You need to do use

`$result->rowCount() == 1`

instead of

`$result == 1`

It really depends what you want to use the result for. If you simply want to tell the user it has been deleted, using what you have is fine.  However, if you want to let the user knows if anything has actually been deleted, you need to use my suggestion above or an alternate method to determine if this is the case.

Comment: As u suggested i have done same but getting this

Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object.

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like you might be using `mysqli` in this code, so maybe you could try using `affected_rows` instead of `rowCount`: 
see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php.

What does

```
$result->affected_rows
```

give you?